# Excel: Excel noob here. Mass transpose. Create an individual company row for every contact in company

Tags: excel, transpose

[image]Right now... my data is formatted like this:

This image above much better explains my current situation.

The first four rows of data is how we are currently set up.

Rows seven to eighteen demonstrate how we want our data to end up!

What path could I be taking to reorganize our data as such?

Thanks again!

Comment: do you mean a single cell has all the information inside it and you need to split that cell by commas into columns? please be more specific, might wanna add some screenshots of before and after.

Comment: @mdelapena Good point! I've posted a picture in an effort to better demonstrate what I want.

Comment: @TerryW Uhm..... the online browser version? Though. I think I have access to Excel 2016.

Comment: If you have Excel 2016, Power Query could be a good fit for the solution.

Comment: @TerryW Uhm. In the actual data set, only contact one has a position. All following contacts just get two means of being able to reach them.... and yeah. There are 4000+ rows that need to be operated on. A way of automating this process is only a little necessary.

Comment: @ThirdGhostHand I am not asking what information is needed to make contact with each contact, I would like to know if your raw data has the same information categories across board, i.e. each contact has `name`, `position`, `email`, etc. Also I am not worry about how many rows you have but I would like to know how many different contacts (ie columns) in your raw data?

Comment: @TerryW Hey Mr. Terry! Let me try to give you more details about the actual data set. 
- There are 2833 ROWS in the data set. Each row represents an individual company. 
- Every contact has three columns. Name. Position. Email. Every contact will have each of those columns populated with information. 
- In every row, the columns are structured like this: Columns A through M just holds information about the company. Columns N through Y are for contacts. N = Contact 1 Name, O = Contact 1 Position, P = Contact 1 Email, and this cycle repeats for every contact.

Comment: I also should mention that while every company row has at least ONE contact, not every company has MORE than one, sometimes leaving columns beyond P unpopulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. It is available in **Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions**. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

Steps are:

1. Use **From Table** function under `Data` tab to add your data (column N to Y) to the power query editor;
2. Use **Merge Columns** function under the `Transform` tab to merge each group of contacts (`Name`,`Position`,`Email`) by delimiter semicolon `;`. At the end of this exercise you should have **8** merged columns (some columns may contain blank cells which is fine) as shown below;

[image: Merge Columns]

3. Highlight all the merged columns, use **Unpivot Columns** function under the `Transform` tab to unpivot these columns, then delete the `Attribute` column, then you should have something like below;

[image: Unpivot Columns]

4. Highlight the `Value` column, use **Split Columns** function under the `Transform` tab to split the column by delimiter semicolon `;`;

[image: Split Columns]

5. Rename the columns as desired, and then filter the second column (which should be the contact name column) to hide blanks;
6. Close & Load the query to a new worksheet (by default)

[image: Result]

Here are the power query **M codes** for your reference. All steps are using built-in functions without advanced coding so should be straight forward and easy to follow. Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Co Name", type text}, {"Contact1", type text}, {"Pos1", type text}, {"Email1", type text}, {"Contact2", type text}, {"Pos2", type any}, {"Email2", type text}, {"Contact3", type text}, {"Pos3", type any}, {"Email3", type text}, {"Contact4", type text}, {"Pos4", type text}, {"Email4", type text}, {"Contact5", type text}, {"Pos5", type text}, {"Email5", type text}, {"Contact6", type text}, {"Pos6", type text}, {"Email6", type text}, {"Contact7", type text}, {"Pos7", type text}, {"Email7", type text}, {"Contact8", type text}, {"Pos8", type text}, {"Email8", type text}}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Contact1", "Pos1", "Email1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns", {{"Pos2", type text}}, "en-AU"),{"Contact2", "Pos2", "Email2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.1"),
    #"Merged Columns2" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns1", {{"Pos3", type text}}, "en-AU"),{"Contact3", "Pos3", "Email3"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.2"),
    #"Merged Columns3" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns2",{"Contact4", "Pos4", "Email4"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.3"),
    #"Merged Columns4" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns3",{"Contact5", "Pos5", "Email5"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.4"),
    #"Merged Columns5" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns4",{"Contact6", "Pos6", "Email6"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.5"),
    #"Merged Columns6" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns5",{"Contact7", "Pos7", "Email7"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.6"),
    #"Merged Columns7" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns6",{"Contact8", "Pos8", "Email8"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.7"),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Merged Columns7", {"Co Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Value.1", "Value.2", "Value.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Value.1", type text}, {"Value.2", type text}, {"Value.3", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Value.1", "Contact"}, {"Value.2", "Position"}, {"Value.3", "Email"}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns", each ([Contact] <> ""))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! The detail in this answer is incredible! Thanks!

Comment: @ThirdGhostHand my pleasure, welcome to the Excel part of the community :) (sorry did not notice you are already a member of SO for over 2 years already)